# decimal years to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, decimal

I have been using a function to convert datetime objects to decimal years based on this post
[python how to convert datetime dates to decimal years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451655/python-how-to-convert-datetime-dates-to-decimal-years)
but I was unable to find any post showing the inverse: decimal years to datetime objects. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not properly tested, but looks about right:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = 2012.5
year = int(start)
rem = start - year

base = datetime(year, 1, 1)
result = base + timedelta(seconds=(base.replace(year=base.year + 1) - base).total_seconds() * rem)
# 2012-07-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: thanks. I converted a datetime array back and forth using the two functions and the result is almost same. Almost because there is a difference of a day in some months, but it it doesn't accumulates over the year.

Answer (score 1):

I found defining a 'base' and calculating down to the second level was unnecssary as the same accuracy seems to be preserved just by using days. I believe this response is less verbose.

```
datetime(int(x), 1, 1) + timedelta(days = (x % 1) * 365)
```

The above 365 can easily be replaced with @PaulMcGuire's recommendation, adapted for days.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following:

Split the decimal year into its integer and fractional part.

Create a datetime object for the 1st of January of the year = integer of decimal year.

Convert the fractional part to seconds.

Add a timedelta(seconds=...) to the datetime object.

Comment: Do all years have the same number of seconds?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I don't think so. But `secondsOfYear = (366 if isLeap(year) else 365) * 24 * 60 * 60` should be close enough. I think no calendar actually uses the real length of each year.

Comment: I was just thinking about the leap years, not leap seconds (your answer didn't mention any allowance for leap years).