# How can I convert the column with years in decimal to a normal datetime (year, month)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, google-colaboratory

I have a dataset of decimal years but I wish to convert this data to the traditional type of datetime: year, month.
[Dataset with decimal years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMe05.png)

I tried with astropy, but it doesn't work. So I'm searching for a solution to my problem. I hope to get an easier visualization of my dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911015/decimal-years-to-datetime-in-python

Answer (score 1):

For a precise vectorial solution, compute the [`divmod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.divmod.html) to get the integer and decimal parts, then add a [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) corresponding to the difference between the beginning and end of this year with the decimal part as a multiplying factor:

```
year, dec = df['decimal_year'].divmod(1)

next_year = pd.to_datetime(year.astype(int).add(1), format='%Y')
year = pd.to_datetime(year.astype(int), format='%Y')
df['date'] = year.add(next_year.sub(year).mul(dec))
```

Output:

```
   decimal_year                          date
0   2019.951214 2019-12-14 04:38:04.703997992
1   2019.952510 2019-12-14 15:59:15.360002360
2   2019.998760 2019-12-31 13:08:15.359998344
3   2020.011751 2020-01-05 07:13:14.822400121
4   2020.020391 2020-01-08 11:06:52.358400563
5   2020.000000 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
6   2020.999999 2020-12-31 23:59:28.377596484
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {'decimal_year': [2019.951214, 2019.952510, 2019.998760,2020.011751,2020.020391]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def decimal_year_to_datetime(decimal_year):
    year = int(decimal_year)
    days_in_year = (decimal_year - year) * 365
    date = datetime(year, 1, 1) + pd.Timedelta(days=days_in_year)
    return date

df['datetime'] = df['decimal_year'].apply(decimal_year_to_datetime)

df['year'] = df['datetime'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['datetime'].dt.month

print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).