# Python datetime to decimal year: one day off, where is the bug?

Tags: python, datetime

I implemented a `datetime.datetime` to decimal year (year fraction) converter based on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451655/python-how-to-convert-datetime-dates-to-decimal-years). I am not getting the expected results but I can't find the bug.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def decimal_year_to_datetime(decimal_year_float):
    year = int(decimal_year_float)
    remain = decimal_year_float - year
    base = datetime(year, 1, 1)
    whole_year_time_delta = (base.replace(year=base.year + 1) - base)
    fractional_seconds = whole_year_time_delta.total_seconds() * remain
    our_time_delta = timedelta(seconds=fractional_seconds)
    result = base + our_time_delta
    return result

def test_conversion():
    year = 2013
    month = 1
    day = 1
    hour = 2
    minute = 16
    second = 48
    date = datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
    fraction_of_the_day = (hour + (minute + second / 60.0) / 60.0) / 24.
    days_in_year = (date.replace(year=date.year + 1) - date).days
    dec_yr = year + (date.timetuple().tm_yday + 
                     fraction_of_the_day) / float(days_in_year)

    expect_date = datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, 
                              hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second)

    got_date = decimal_year_to_datetime(dec_yr)

    assert(got_date == expect_date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_conversion()
```

I seem to be a day (an and a fraction of a second) off with my conversion. But I cannot see the bug.

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: note: [the accepted answer in the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6451892/4279) may take into account changes in the local utc offset for whatever reasons otherwise you may introduce an hour error (e.g., 2014 year in Europe/Moscow timezone). It is rare and it introduces only `~1e-4` error -- see whether you can ignore it in your case. `time.mktime()` may reduce the error to `~6e-8` on some systems (if your input is known within a couple of seconds then it is enough).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're out by one day (a classic fencepost error!) because, although we consider 1st January to to be day one of the year, in computing terms that's **the zeroth day**. The simplest fix is to add in a `- 1`, but your approach seems generally quite complex; I would do it as follows:

```
def dt_to_dec(dt):
    """Convert a datetime to decimal year."""
    year_start = datetime(dt.year, 1, 1)
    year_end = year_start.replace(year=dt.year+1)
    return dt.year + ((dt - year_start).total_seconds() /  # seconds so far
        float((year_end - year_start).total_seconds()))  # seconds in year
```

In use:

```
>>> dec = dt_to_dec(datetime(2013, 1, 1, 2, 16, 48))
>>> dec
2013.0002602739726
>>> decimal_year_to_datetime(dec)
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 2, 16, 47, 999999)
```

*(given floating point accuracy, that's as close as you're likely to get...)*

Comment: On Python 3, you could write it as `dt.year + (dt - year_start) / (year_end - year_start)`. Note: [it assumes that `dt`, `year_start`, `year_end` dates all have the same utc offset. Otherwise It may introduce an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851357/python-datetime-to-decimal-year-one-day-off-where-is-the-bug?lq=1#comment47838933_29851357)